# How do I add Guna UI in the Jetbrains Rider toolbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, rider

I got GunaUI from NuGet and I cannot add it in the Jetbrains Rider toolbox. I can only use it in Visual Studio where you don't have to add it.
How do I add it in Rider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GunaUI Framework has been developed for VS IDE and I don't think if you can use it in other IDEs that represent Winforms Developement.